# Lookup and Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have some columns in sheet 1 (here in image O and P columns), and in another sheet (here in image R, S, T, U, V, W). I want to check the matching `Date` and `Number` from sheet 1 with `Date` and `Number` with sheet 2, and then do conditional formatting to highlight that particular row in sheet 2.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a custom formula to R2:W in conditional formatting that reads:

> =if($R2="",false,match(join("-",$S2,$R2),byrow($O$2:$O,lambda(each,join("-",each,offset(each,0,1)))),0))

It joins both columns in the correct orders and finds a match in the corresponding column also joined of the left

[image]

---

Option 2:

```
=IF($R2="",false,QUERY($O:$P,"Select O where O = "&$S2&" AND P = date '"&text($R2,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"'"))
```

Comment: Thanks. That's a great help, but it seems it will take a lots of time to load the formula for huge data.

Comment: You can set a new column (say Q) with that Byrow function, and just replace the formula with: =if($R2="",false,match(join("-",$S2,$R2),Q:Q,0)) That would be much faster, since the calculations are done just once

Comment: You could also just try with a QUERY: =IF($R2="",false,QUERY($O:$P,"Select O where O = "&$S2&" AND P = date '"&text($R2,"YYYY-MM-DD")&"'")) - VLOOKUP won't work with more than one variable, this would be its alternative

Comment: Thanks, but still cant handle a huge data. Is there a way I can add a new column with values as "PAID" if found the match and blank if nothing found?

Comment: Mmm, yes, obviously you can, but the approach would be similar, son't know if it would mean much difference in time. Have you tried adding that Q column?? That would diminish considerably the time of processing

Comment: Yes tried with Q column but still taking time to work on it. So, it would be better with that PAID approach, then I can apply conditional formatting to color out the PAID part

Comment: @satyabansahoo Yes, you are right, `=COUNTIFS($O$2:$O,$S2,$P$2:$P,$R2)` will run slightly faster

Comment: Thanks. Got the solution.